# FPDF doesn't show mysql data

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, fpdf

I have a problem using FPDF for create PDF reports on PHP. I've a mysql query for load the data of one table and I want to show it into a PDF file but when I'm fetching the results I can't see anything in my PDF report. If I try to write something out the while loop it appears but if I write it into the loop it doesn't appear.
It's the code for creating the PDF.

```
    $apellidos="Perez Martin";
    $pdf=new PDF('L','mm','A4');
    $pdf->AliasNbPages();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $mysqli=new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $clave, $basedatos);
    $mysqli->set_charset("latin1");
    if($mysqli->connect_error){
        echo "Error nº ".$conexion->connect_errno.": ".$conexion->connect_error;
    }
    $result=$mysqli->query("SELECT E1.Nombre EquipoA, E2.Nombre EquipoB, DATE_FORMAT(Fecha, '%d/%m/%Y'), TIME_FORMAT(Hora, '%H:%i'), Abreviatura, Tipo, LOCALIDAD.Nombre Localidad, PA.Nombre, PA.Codigo_pabellon Pista, 
    CONCAT(A1.Apellidos,', ', A1.Nombre) ArbPrin, CONCAT(A2.Apellidos,', ', A2.Nombre) ArbAux, CONCAT(A3.Apellidos,', ', A3.Nombre) Anotador, CONCAT(A4.Apellidos,', ', A4.Nombre) Crono, CONCAT(A5.Apellidos,', ', A5.Nombre) Op24, CONCAT(A6.Apellidos,', ', A6.Nombre) Coche
    FROM PARTIDO P INNER JOIN EQUIPO E1 ON P.EquipoA=E1.Codigo_equipo 
    INNER JOIN EQUIPO E2 ON P.EquipoB=E2.Codigo_equipo 
    INNER JOIN PABELLON PA ON P.Codigo_pabellon=PA.Codigo_pabellon 
    INNER JOIN CATEGORIA ON P.Codigo_categoria=CATEGORIA.Codigo_categoria
    INNER JOIN LOCALIDAD ON  PA.Codigo_localidad=LOCALIDAD.Codigo_localidad
    INNER JOIN SEDE ON LOCALIDAD.Codigo_sede=SEDE.Codigo_sede
    LEFT JOIN EQUIPO_ARBITRAL A1 ON A1.Codigo_arbitro=P.ArbPrin
    LEFT JOIN EQUIPO_ARBITRAL A2 ON A2.Codigo_arbitro=P.ArbAux
    LEFT JOIN EQUIPO_ARBITRAL A3 ON A3.Codigo_arbitro=P.Anotador
    LEFT JOIN EQUIPO_ARBITRAL A4 ON A4.Codigo_arbitro=P.Crono
    LEFT JOIN EQUIPO_ARBITRAL A5 ON A5.Codigo_arbitro=P.Op24
    LEFT JOIN EQUIPO_ARBITRAL A6 ON A6.Codigo_arbitro=P.Coche
    WHERE A1.Apellidos LIKE '%$apellidos%' OR A2.Apellidos LIKE '%$apellidos%' 
    OR A3.Apellidos LIKE '%$apellidos%' OR A4.Apellidos LIKE '%$apellidos%' OR
    A5.Apellidos LIKE '%$apellidos%' OR A6.Apellidos LIKE '%$apellidos%'
    ORDER BY Fecha, Hora");
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
    $pdf->Cell(210);
    $pdf->Cell(30,10, 'Principal');
    $pdf->Cell(30,10, 'Anotador');
    $pdf->Ln(5);
    $pdf->Cell(210);
    $pdf->Cell(30,10, 'Auxiliar');
    $pdf->Cell(30,10, 'Cronometrador');
    $pdf->Ln(5);
    $pdf->Cell(20);
    $pdf->Cell(70,10,'Encuentro');
    $pdf->Cell(30,10, 'Fecha');
    $pdf->Cell(30,10, 'Hora');
    $pdf->Cell(30,10, 'Categoria');
    $pdf->Cell(30,10, 'Compet.');
    $pdf->Cell(30,10, 'Coche');
    $pdf->Cell(30,10, 'Operador 24"');
    $pdf->Ln(10);
    $pdf->Cell(0,0,'',1);
    $pdf->Cell(0,0,'',1);
    $pdf->Ln(1);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 12);
    while($row=$result->fetch_array()){ 
        $pdf->Cell(15,10,$row["EquipoA"]);
        $pdf->Cell(15,10,$row["EquipoB"]);
        $pdf->Cell(30,10,$row["Fecha"]);
        $pdf->Cell(30,10,$row["Hora"]);
        $pdf->Cell(30,10,$row["Abreviatura"]);
        $pdf->Cell(30,10,$row["Tipo"]);
        $pdf->Cell(30,10,$row["ArbPrin"]);
        $pdf->Cell(30,10,$row["Anotador"]);
        $pdf->Ln(1);
        $pdf->Cell(240);
        $pdf->Cell(30,10,$row["ArbAux"]);
        $pdf->Cell(30,10,$row["Crono"]);
        $pdf->Ln(1);
        $pdf->Cell(30,10,'Localidad: ');
        $pdf->Cell(30,10,$row["Localidad"]);
        $pdf->Cell(80);
        $pdf->Cell(30,10,'Pista: ');
        $pdf->Cell(30,10,$row["Pista"]);
        $pdf->Cell(40);
        $pdf->Cell(30,10,$row["Op24"]);
        $pdf->Cell(30,10,$row["Coche"]);
    }
    $pdf->Output();
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

Comment: Sidenote: You will not see any errors for DB if you use `$conexion` since your DB connection is `$mysqli`

Comment: It only show errors on conection. All the query it's ok. I try it in another PHP script and I can see all the data of the query. The problem is in while loop but I don't know what will be that problem.